# Center input type text inside a form inside div inside a wordpress page?

Tags: css, forms, wordpress, input

I've created a simple get method form and am having trouble centering the input box. The code works fine out of wordpress, but when I insert into a wordpress page, the input box becomes mis-aligned.

Here's the code I'm inserting on the wordpress page.

```
<div class="homebox"> 
<form method="get" action="/home-quote-page.html" form name="quote" rel="nofollow" onsubmit="return ray.ajax()"> 
<p class="topquotetext">Enter your zip code:</p>
<p><input name="zipcode" class="zipbox" type="text" value="" size="5" maxlength="5"/>       </p>
<p><div style="getquote"><input type="image" src="/Photos/startquote.gif" alt="Start Your Quote" name="go" value='Submit'/></div></form></p>
<div id="load" style="display:none;">Finding...Please wait.</div>   
</div>
```

Here's the css. Everything works fine except .zipbox it will allow me to change the color of the box and the height but that's it. No matter what number I input into the width of the box it stays the same width, it also doesn't center inside the div.

```
.homebox {
text-align: center;
width: 300px;
height: 268px; 
background: #2872bd url(/Photos/home-insurance-box.jpg) no-   repeat; }

.topquotetext {
font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana; 
font-size:16px; 
color:#ffffff;
padding-top:70px;
text-align: center;
}

.zipbox {
width: 95px;
height: 25px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 5px;
border: #7F9DB9 1px solid;
background-color: #FFFED2;
}

.getquote {
width: 300px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: OT: Please change `<p class="topquotetext">Enter your zip code:</p>` to `<label for="zipcode" class="topquotetext">Enter your zip code:</label> <input id="zipcode" name="zipcode" class="zipbox" type="text" value="" size="5" maxlength="5"/>` so it is accessible for people with disabilities

Answer (score 0):

Are you pasting this into the default WYSIWYG in WP? If so, WP is stripping out some of your markup. Find a plugin that will allow you to paste in markup, or create a new template and hard-code this section.

Comment: No I'm inputting it into the html tab, not the visual tab on the edit page screen. Do you know any plugins that do this?

Comment: I figured it out. I just had to use input.zipbox in the css! doh!

Comment: Keep in mind the HTML tab will strip out some markup if you switch back and forth between it and the WYSIWYG. Any easy fix is to turn off the WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it would be centered if you use `margin-left: 10px;` on the .zipbox and `text-align: center` would not make element centerd, just text which will be centered. There's nothing wrong with WordPress, it's just how you style the element.

Try this, a bit change of your stylesheet.

```
.zipbox {
    width: 95px;
    height: 25px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: #7F9DB9 1px solid;
    background-color: #FFFED2;
}
```

And also make sure that the parent element style not affecting the `.zipbox` and you don't need to wrap the `<input />` element in `<p></p>`, wrap it with `<div></div>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. It seems like your right, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Try to set the with of the 'form' to 100% with a position: relative;